# Why does the robot tell me to get a helmet?

Tags: zelda-skyward-sword

In *The Legend of Zelda: Skyward Sword* in the Lanayru Mine, one of the LD-301 robots tells me "So you're looking for work? Well come back when you have a helmet."

What does this mean? I'm almost at the end of the game (I have completed all the Silent Realms and have the best shield) and have no helmet. Is it a joke? If not, where can I get the helmet?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is indeed a joke (or at least not a serious request). There is no sidequest available for that particular NPC.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't find it very funny, I guess I didn't get it :-)